# Confusion with Hard Disk structure

Tags: storage

Studying Os development I encountered the need to interface with the Hard Disk Drive and thus i started learning how it actually works.
One of the problems that i found studying was that different sources said and claimed different things about the Hard Drive's structure.
So, i have some questions:

1. Is a Sector a Geometrical Sector of the Platter or an area inside a Cylinder/Track? (i naturally opt for the second)
2. Is there a difference between Cylinders and Tracks? (some claims it)
3. In CHS (Cylinder, Head, Sector) addressing mode when incrementing the value of Head do you actually change the Platter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We generally prefer that you ask one question per post.  Our site format usually works better that way.  You can create multiple posts with one question per post.

Comment: I suggest reviewing material in Wikipedia, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_(disk_drive), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector.  I think you'll find some relevant information there.

Comment: @Steven thank you very much!

Comment: @D.W. thank you very much!

Comment: Of interest: [Discovering Hard Disk Physical Geometry through Microbenchmarking](https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2019/09/hard-disk-geometry-microbenchmarking/) This will keep you busy for some time if you really want to know the details.

Comment: While I can not quickly find references two things that I know are worth checking are 1. I recall that drives made for streaming data like movies might actually forgo sectors and grab entire tracks. 2. To get more data on to newer drives they overlap the tracks and then if a track is updated all the overlapping tracks have to be refreshed. I think I learned that one from [Linus Tech Tips](https://www.youtube.com/c/linustechtips)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but here is how I understand it.

1. A sector describes a radial slice of each platter, i.e., it contains a portion of each track. The term is somewhat ambiguous as it is often used to refer to a particular portion of a given track. Wikipedia calls the former a "geometrical sector" and the latter a "disk sector". See B and C in the following figure from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector):

[image: sector]

2. A cylinder is the collection of all tracks on all platters at the same distance from the spindle.
3. You either go to another platter or to the other side of the same platter (if the disk has heads on both sides).